# System of periodic equations and Floquet multiplier

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Ferguson in his [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2006386) in 1980 studied properties of periodic Jacobi matrices which is the following matrix

$$
 A = \begin{bmatrix}
 a_1&b_1&0&0&0&0& \cdots & b_n\\
 b_1&a_2&b_2&0&0&0&\cdots&0\\
 0&b_2&a_3&b_3&0&0&\cdots&0\\
 0&0&b_3&a_4&b_4&0&\cdots&0\\
 0&0&0&b_4&a_5&b_5&\cdots&0\\
 0&0&0&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
 0&0&0&0&0&b_{n-2}&a_{n-1}&b_{n-1}\\
 b_n&0&0&0&0&0&b_{n-1}&a_n
 \end{bmatrix}
$$

For a given eigenpair $(\lambda, X)$ of $A$ where $X = [x_1, \dots, x_n]$  we have

$$
b_{i-1}x_{i-1} + a_ix_i + b_ix_{i+1} = \lambda x_i, \text{ for } i=1, \cdots, n
$$

such that $b_0 = b_n, x_0=x_n, x_{n+1} = x_1$. He solved this system of linear equations to build such matrix. In fact it is an inverse eigenvalue problem, constructing a matrix of a specific form from spectral data.

There is something I can't understand is this statement

> By analogy with Floquet theory, which analyzes the analogous problem for ordinary differential equations, let us consider the nontrivial solutions of this recurrence relation which satisfy the boundary conditions
>   $$
> z_n = \rho z_0, z_{n+1} = \rho z_1
> $$
>   Here the parameter $\rho$ is called the Floquet multiplier of the solution $x$. For $\rho \neq 0$ a nontrivial solution exists if and only if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $$
>  L = \begin{bmatrix}
>  a_1&b_1&0&0&0&0& \cdots & \dfrac{1}{\rho} b_n\\
>  b_1&a_2&b_2&0&0&0&\cdots&0\\
>  0&b_2&a_3&b_3&0&0&\cdots&0\\
>  0&0&b_3&a_4&b_4&0&\cdots&0\\
>  0&0&0&b_4&a_5&b_5&\cdots&0\\
>  0&0&0&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
>  0&0&0&0&0&b_{n-2}&a_{n-1}&b_{n-1}\\
>  \rho b_n&0&0&0&0&0&b_{n-1}&a_n
>  \end{bmatrix}
> $$

How did he apply the Floquet theory to this problem? There is no function, derivative or differential equations here, it is just a system of periodic linear equations.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the paper link. It's right down my alley.
The fact that the matrix is three band connects it to ordinary differential operator of second order by $$\frac{d}{dx}(a(x)\frac{df(x)}{dx})+b(x)f(x)\approx a(x_{k-1})(f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1}))+a(x_{k+1})(f(x_k)-f(x_{k+1}))+b(x_k)f(x_k).$$ Where $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ should be discretized with some care. The eigenvalues $\rho$ correspond to eigenvalues of the monodoromy of the differential operator. In general $2n-1$ band matrix corresponds to $n$th order differential operator/equation. 
I've developed a whole theory connecting discrete/difference equations and continuous/differential equations Floquet multipliers. There is a beautiful connection to continued fractions. Here are my PhD thesis and a paper on the subject. Please, do not hesitate to ask more questions on the topic.

https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxkYXZlZGNsdWJ8Z3g6MTczNjY5NzM5YTA4YmUzYw

https://www.academia.edu/35236460/Parameter_continuation_of_the_circular_domain_boundary_value_map